# Toast based on reducer change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list of items, in which I can perform 'replace multiple items based on some condition'. Once the items are replaced, I need to show a toast saying 'X items replaced'.

Here 'X' is known only to the reducer.

If calling an action creator from reducer is an anti-pattern, what's the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Toast reducer that responds to the same action.

Comment: But it wont be aware of the value for 'X'.

Comment: So X is the result of response to your current reducer? If so https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions may help. The actions are not called from the reducer they are just called from the action creator.